# Generate an array using DateInterval and DatePeriod for shifts

Tags: php, arrays, date, intervals, chunks

I'm using DateInterval and DatePeriod to generate shifts in a medical application

```
$begin = new DateTime('2012-08-01 08:00');
$end = new DateTime('2012-08-01 12:00');
$interval = new DateInterval('PT45M');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
```

Those functions allow me to generate the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 08:00
    [1] => 08:45
    [2] => 09:30
    [3] => 10:15
    [4] => 11:00
    [5] => 11:45
)
```

**Which functions and how could I do so the final array gets completed and chunked as this?**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08:00
            [1] => 08:45
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08:45
            [1] => 09:30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09:30
            [1] => 10:15
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10:15
            [1] => 11:00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11:00
            [1] => 11:45
        )
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$previous = null;
$dates    = array();
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $current = $dt->format("H:i");
    if (!empty($previous)) {
        $show = new DateTime($current);
        $dates[] = array($previous, $show->format('H:i'));
    }
    $previous = $current;
}
```

Comment: Hi john. I've tried and it works perfect, but If I set the interval to PT30M and begin: 2012-08-01 08:00 end: 2012-08-01 10:00, it does not take into account the "final shift", but I think it could be due a bug in DatePeriod function?

Comment: @Enrique DatePeriod will skip the last iteration if it is exactly the length of the interval. Add one second or minute to your `$end` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. Works perfect but hope some day DatePeriod to have a parameter that allows to include last interval

Answer (score 1):

After retrieve your array using `DateTime` function. Just Plug n Play with the code. :)

```
$retrieveArray = array('08:00','08:45','09:30','10:15','11:00','11:45'); // Sample Array, Assumed mentioned in Question.

$final = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($retrieveArray)-1; $i++) { 
    $j = $i+1;
    $final[$i] = array($retrieveArray[$i], $retrieveArray[$j]);
}
```

Use `var_dump($final);` to check array result.

### Desired Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08:00
            [1] => 08:45
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08:45
            [1] => 09:30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09:30
            [1] => 10:15
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10:15
            [1] => 11:00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11:00
            [1] => 11:45
        )

)
```

**Edit:**

**To Add Last Shift**

@jhon is right. It skips the last boundary value if it matches exactly the length of the interval.
As you need it, I suggest to *ADD* `+1 min` to your end time. It's a tweak/fix but server the purpose.

```
$begin = new DateTime('2012-08-01 08:00');
$end = new DateTime('2012-08-01 10:00');
$end = $end->modify( '+1 minute' ); // Tweak, to add last shift value.
$interval = new DateInterval('PT30M');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
```

**To Check Output**

```
foreach ( $daterange as $dt ){
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $dt->format( "H:i" );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

It is including last boundary value if it matches exactly the length of the interval.

Comment: Hi Abhineet. I've tried your code and it works perfect, but If I set the interval to PT30M and set $begin: 2012-08-01 08:00, $end: 2012-08-01 10:00, it does not take into account the "final shift" which is 09:30 to 10:00. Do you think it could be a DatePeriod bug, and how could you solve? I must be able to change interval period, start and end time and to be able to generate the shifts perfectly. thanks

Comment: @Enrique Just updated my answer. I suggest you to add +1min in your last time. Adding value is fine until it is not exceeding the interval value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Abhineet. Worked perfectly!